# Heroku deploying with Git Node.js multer uploads folder Inspect files

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I have a Node.js application. I host this application on Heroku and I am deploying the app with Git. I have [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) built in and I store uploaded files in an upload folder in the application.

So my question: Is there a way to inspect the files in the folder in the application hosted on Heroku?

`$ heroku git:clone -a YOUR_APP_NAME` does not work, because I am deploying with Github.

Response: `warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.`

Thanks a lot for the effort.

Comment: I solve it with accessing the URL, the file is available: http://www.myapp.io/uploads/myfile.rtf - Maybe this helps somebody else.

Comment: Note that Heroku filesystem is ephemeral, so those files will go away when the application restarts. You should be storing elsewhere (eg Amazon S3 or git) if you want real persistence

Comment: Yes thanks for the comment, I want to refactor this code anyway.